# Google Play store crashes and gapps process not working since upgrading to Jelly Bean on Samsung Galaxy S II

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.2-jelly-bean

My phone is about 9 months old and has not given me any problems before I upgraded to the latest Android version - Jelly Bean 4.1.2. I downloaded an original version (not a cracked version) when I got an upgrade for my phone. However, since then, while I try to launch the Google Apps store, it just crashes and I'm unable to browse the store, forget downloading new apps!

It hangs often now - while typing a message or browsing on the phone, I randomly get the message - Something like, **gapps.process** is not responding and has stopped.

I reckon, I shall have to format and re-install the Jelly Bean again on my phone. *I'm open to suggestions though :D*

1. I do not have Kies pre-installed on my laptop yet. Will it cause an issue? If needed, where do I download it from?
2. My phone is not rooted - I would not like to root my phone as yet.
3. Would appreciate only *legal* methods, as I'm worried about my warranty on my phone.
4. My phone memory - contacts (extremely important) and apps(if possible) need to be safe.
5. I would like to keep the data on my data card ( music, videos ) safe.

I do a bit on my S II (I9100G), but I'm no real expert with the phone. Appreciate a tested way..!

Comment: You won't need Kies for that (how does that make the phone more stable when installed on the laptop? Are you carrying the laptop around with you, permanently connected? ;) One thing you *could* try is to factory-reset the device (beware: this will delete all your data and apps, so make a good backup before -- do not solely rely on "Google Cloud Backup", as a) this doesn't include all app data, and b) it's not really reliable). If that doesn't solve the issue, it's time to call the service; it was *their* update which broke it...

Answer (score 1):

No need for a factory reset, friend.
All you have to do is go to Settings>Application Manager>All>Download Manager>Clear Cache and Clear Data.
Go to Google Play>Clear Cache>Clear Data and then Go to Google Play Services>Clear Cache>ClearData.
REstart the Phone and it will be alright.